# Convert list of dicts with dicts as values to ML features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

I want to transform the output of Google Vision API facial recognition into a feature set for a ML classifier. For each training instance I get a list of predicted faces which is represented as a list of dictionaries where the values are themselves dictionaries and the values of these 'value dictionaries' are categorical in nature like this:

```
$ faces[191:197]


[{'face_1': {'joy': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'surprise': 'UNLIKELY',
   'anger': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'sorrow': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'headwear': 'VERY_UNLIKELY'}},
 {},
 {},
 {'face_1': {'joy': 'VERY_LIKELY',
   'surprise': 'LIKELY',
   'anger': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'sorrow': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'headwear': 'VERY_UNLIKELY'},
  'face_2': {'joy': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'surprise': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'anger': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'sorrow': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'headwear': 'VERY_LIKELY'}},
 {'face_1': {'joy': 'VERY_LIKELY',
   'surprise': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'anger': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'sorrow': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'headwear': 'VERY_UNLIKELY'},
  'face_2': {'joy': 'POSSIBLE',
   'surprise': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'anger': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'sorrow': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
   'headwear': 'VERY_UNLIKELY'}}]
```

My ambition is to transform this into a ML readable format. I would like to use an encoding that looks like this (n is the maximum number of predicted faces in the entire dataset):

```
         joy_1  surprise_1 , ...., anger_n    sorrow_n    headwear_n
img_1      1       2       , ....,  0           0            0
img_2      0       0       , ....,  0           0            0
img_3      0       0       , ....,  0           0            0
img_4      5       4       , ....,  0           0            0
  .
  .
  .
```

I have used sklearn dictVectorizer and labelEncoder for other features that were lists of dicts but those dicts didn't have dicts as values as is the case for this data source.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the rows represent in your desired output? Do you want to convert each value in `faces` to a row?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes each row represents an image that was parsed through Google Vision API. For each face in an image, the GVA engine yields a score for each of following 5 fields "joy/surprise/anger/sorrow/headwear". Prediction scores fall into categories "VERY_UNLIKELY/UNLIKELY/POSSIBLE/LIKELY/VERY LIKELY". These categories are not independent so wish to transform them to scores between 0-5 (0 denotes 'not observed' and 5 'highly likely'). There are 0-8 faces in each image so I will end up with 40 features (5 facial expressions for each of 8 potential faces).
Hope it made sense?

Comment: So to sum, yes each row in the desired output represents a single image.

Comment: You can do two things. Convert dict to dataframe. Then use an categorical encoder to encode your stings to integers. First convert to df. Then a simple google search can yield a solution to encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything that would work out-of-the-box that handles mapping ordinal values (`VERY_UNLIKELY`, ..., `VERY_LIKELY`) to integers in a user-defined way while also handling possible keys in dictionaries.

Something like the following would probably be easiest here:

```py
# Include `images` list-of-dicts from question

# images = [{'face_1': {'joy': 'VERY_UNLIKELY',
#            ...]

import numpy as np

observations = ["joy", "surprise", "anger", "sorrow", "headwear"]
levels = {
    "VERY_UNLIKELY": 0,
    "UNLIKELY": 1,
    "POSSIBLE": 2,
    "LIKELY": 3,
    "VERY_LIKELY": 4,
}

N_IMAGES = len(images)
N_OBSERVATIONS = len(observations)
N_PEOPLE_PER_IMAGE = 2

vector = np.zeros((N_IMAGES, N_PEOPLE_PER_IMAGE * N_OBSERVATIONS))

for i, image in enumerate(images):
    for j, face in enumerate(image):
        if not face:
            continue
        else:
            t = (j * N_OBSERVATIONS)
            e = (j * N_OBSERVATIONS) + N_OBSERVATIONS
            obs_vector = [levels[image[face][obs]] for obs in observations]
            vector[i][t:e] = obs_vector

print(vector)
```

Result:

```
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [4. 3. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 4.]
 [4. 0. 0. 0. 0. 2. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

If there are up to 8 faces in each image, this could easily be extended by setting `N_PEOPLE_PER_IMAGE = 8`.